# BinaryFormatter and Deserialize. How to stop at end of stream?

Tags: c#, serialization, filestream

this can probably be done with a foreach loop. However.. while / for should also work. If I have a class MyClass, and writes 100 objects of MyClass. How can I stop at end of file when i Deserialize? Thanks in Advance

```
FileStream inStr = new FileStream(@"file.dat", FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

while (???) // What to put here? EOF / End of stream check
{
myclass = (MyClass)bf.Deserialize(inStr);
//...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to save and load a list of your `MyClass` why not save a List object.

#### Save

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
// add to your list
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"file.dat", FileMode.Create);
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(stream, list);
stream.Close();
```

#### Load

```
FileStream inStr = new FileStream(@"file.dat", FileMode.Open);
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
List<MyClass> list = bf.Deserialize(inStr) as List<MyClass>;
```

Comment: I can't because I use a class from a DLL wich isn't serialized... I have a list of objects and serialize them to another class, MyClass. So... Oh, yeah I could do a new list! :)

Comment: This should work, yes. If you have a serializable class you can do this.

Comment: You should use "using" statements so it automatically disposes.

Comment: `stream.Close()` at the end of `load()`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
while (inStr.Length != inStr.Position)
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use

```
While(Stream.Peek != -1)
```

Comment: Error 1 'System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'Peek'

Comment: in your code it would be 'While(inStr.Peek != -1)'. it should be clear that an instance of a stream is required and you only have one in your code....

Comment: No, there is no Peek for inStr. It's an FileStream object, not Stream.. probably why?